# How do I set an lldb breakpoint in init of objc class

Tags: xcode, lldb

I'm investigating where an offending misconfigured alertcontroller is made/presented

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Your application has presented a UIAlertController
>   () of style
>   UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet from UP.BVTabBarViewController
>   (). The modalPresentationStyle
>   of a UIAlertController with this style is UIModalPresentationPopover.
>   You must provide location information for this popover through the
>   alert controller's popoverPresentationController. You must provide
>   either a sourceView and sourceRect or a barButtonItem.  If this
>   information is not known when you present the alert controller, you
>   may provide it in the UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate method
>   -prepareForPopoverPresentation.

Naively I've tried this:

```
(lldb)  br s -n "-[UIAlertController init]"
Breakpoint 100: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

What's the proper (working) way?

Comment: Why do you need a breakpoint?  It’s obvious what the bug is; why don’t you just fix it? Search in your code for `actionSheet`. An action sheet on an iPad must always be configured as a popover, with an arrow source.

Comment: I have about a dozen of call sites and would rather dodge the "joy" of adding 12 breakpoints to identify misconfigured alertcontroller instance

Comment: But it will be visually immediately obvious. It will be the one that doesn't configure the popover! A dozen is not many. It will be much faster to look at them all than to run the app over and over trying to make the faulty one appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're doing this completely wrong, your alert controllers are all created by calling

```
+[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:message:preferredStyle:]
```

However, there is really no need for this breakpoint, and it won't help you because you won't encounter the breakpoint unless you summon the particular alert that is causing the problem. Instead, just search your code globally for `.actionSheet` and fix the one that isn't configured as a popover.

The rule is that on iPad all action sheets must be explicitly given a source view or source bar button item for the arrow to point to; it will be immediately obvious when you come to an action sheet for which you're not doing that.

Comment: ok, only 4 out of gthe dozen were actionsheets. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

To provide a more generic answer, for any class you can do:

```
br s -r '-\[UISomeClass init'
br s -r '\+\[UISomeClass '
```

The first creates a breakpoint on any method starting with `init`. The second matches all class methods, and creates breakpoints for each.

There is one case that neither approach covers: superclass methods. Maybe not a concern for `UIAlertController`, but in general breakpoints can only be set like this on the methods the class implements, not on inherited methods.

Comment: makes me wonder if there is any recorse when you have to deal with the facade classes such as nsarray or nsstring...

Comment: You can also set a breakpoint on a selector (`break set -S`) but for something like `init` that's probably going to have too many hits to be useful.  If it was in your own code, limiting the breakpoint to your executable might make this slightly more palatable...

Comment: It would be neat to have `--in-class-hierarchy-of` and `--derives-from` modifiers to selector breakpoints that would limit breakpoints to classes in the class hierarchy of or deriving from the given class.  It looks like the NSArray/NSString implementation classes do derive from NSArray/NSString...  Note, you could actually make such a thing in Python using scripted breakpoint resolvers if you were sufficiently motivated.